# Is this a secure connection?

Tags: javascript, https

I have a function that opens new browser tab and loads a lot of data into it:

```
var contact_id = $('#contact_id).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'contacts.php',
    data: 'id' + contact_id,
    success: function(data) {
        var win = window.open("data:text/html, " + encodecURIComponent(data));
        win.focus();
    }
});
```

The users connects thought https protocol and clicks on a link with a contact name to get additional data on this new tab page. But when this new tab gets opened it doesn't specify what protocol it is. Seems like the data being given out unsecurely, am I correct?

I have tried to replace this line:

```
var win = window.open("data:text/html, " + encodecURIComponent(data));
```

to this one:

```
var win = window.open("https:text/html, " + encodecURIComponent(data));
```

But then I get ***Request-URI Too Large (Apache)***.

Please help.

Comment: Well, take a look at the http servers log files or examine the request in your browsers development console. Both locations log details about the request as they are performed.

Comment: I have Chrome, what do I check in the developer tool, "Network"?

Comment: Sure. That is where all requests done by the browser after opening the console are logged and can be examined.

Comment: WIth a mouse hover I see that request goes to https://domain/contacts.php, but then new page gets opened which I don't trace, I belive Chrome has one Console per tab

Comment: Oh, I get it, if it goes https one diretion then it comes https too.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "text/html" part of the argument is the content-type, it has nothing to do with the transport protocol http or https.

However, what you are doing is simply displaying the results of the POST in a new window, you are not performing a new request to the server. So, you only have to worry about the original POST being sent over https.

You can confirm this in the network tab of google chrome dev tools for example.

Comment: The data value returns html string starting with <html><head> etc. it is a whole page, not url

Comment: Ohh, my mistake, I realize now you had "data:", I'll edit my answer.